# Why is my call to my rails back end causing my React to grab the public/index.html file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have been following a tutorial (https://github.com/fullstackreact/food-lookup-demo-rails) to set up a react front end and rails back end.  The tutorial itself works fine.  However, when I deviate and try some of my own code, things don't work out at all.  My deviations are that I am using a different controller and model.  However, I have copied everything else from the tutorial.

When I fetch from my local rails api, then I get back the public/index.html file located in the react folder.  When I fetch a random api, like:

https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty

then the api is properly consumed and it's json.

When I query the back end by just visiting localhost:3000/api/stories, I get a json output.

Below is the App.js file for React

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/api/stories")
    // .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the controller for the stories api

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @stories = Story.limit(2)
        render(
            status: 200,
         json: @stories.to_json
        )
    end
end
```

following is the package.json, to show that I set the proxy route correctly:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ],
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"
  }
}
```

thank you for any insights

Answer (score 0):

Base on the tutorial you provide, you should host your API server at localhost:3001. You can check the [readme](https://github.com/fullstackreact/food-lookup-demo-rails#overview) for more information.

[image]